# Nodejs AsyncLocalStorage getStore() return undefined

Tags: node.js, async-hooks

I read this post [AsyncLocalStorage for Easy Context Passing in Node.js](https://medium.com/trabe/asynclocalstorage-for-easy-context-passing-in-node-js-e33c84679516)
I try to get logId in my logs, but i cant, beacause `asyncLocalStorage.getStore()` return undefined.
It seems that context was lost inside MyLogger class.
How to solve it?

Here is my express App

```
  const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
          asyncLocalStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
            asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set("requestId", uuid());
            next();
          });
        });
    
    module.exports.asyncLocalStorage = asyncLocalStorage;
```

Here is MyLogger class

```
   static log(logId, className, text) {
    const { asyncLocalStorage } = require("../server.js");
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore()
    console.log(this._getBaseStaticLog(logId, logTypes.LOG, text, className));
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the same instance AsyncLocalStorage for both places?

Comment: @Buggy no. let me try.

Comment: @Buggy i use same storage, but result same here code https://pastebin.com/zHPEiXu8

Comment: @Masquitos, do you know why bodyParser loses the context? Or how to solve it? I'm facing the same problem, but I can't change their order

Comment: @Doc999tor Unfortunately no. its is because i use express middelware, i donw know how to fix it in epress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solve the problem.
The problem was that i lose context due to `bodyparser` middleware.
I change that middleware before set context, and now its ok.
Was:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  asyncLocalStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
    asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set("requestId", uuid());
    next();
  });
});

// body parser
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10mb"
  })
);
```

Change:

```
// body parser
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10mb"
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  asyncLocalStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
    asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set("requestId", uuid());
    next();
  });
});
```

And now its ok)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem also

Comment: Weird... I wonder why

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when using `express.json()`. I also had to change the order of my middleware to make the `AsyncLocalStorage` work properly, like this:

```
app.use(loggerMiddleware);

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    LOGGER.info("new request", {
        originalUrl: req.originalUrl,
        body: req.body,
    });
    next();
});
```

To this:

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(loggerMiddleware);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    LOGGER.info("new request", {
        originalUrl: req.originalUrl,
        body: req.body,
    });
    next();
});
```

Where `loggerMiddleware` is the logger that runs `asyncLocalStorage.run()` and `LOGGER.info` is my logger that access the content of `asyncLocalStorage`.

This seems to be documented: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4396